# Getting Error in Scroll View Component of Kendo UI for angular2

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

i am currently working on angular2 project which uses kendo-ui scrollview for angular2
today when i open my code and did npm install and run the project i an getting error
here is full stack trace']

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("          <span class="k-icon k-i-arrowhead-e"></span>
    </a>
    <kendo-scrollview-pager [ERROR ->]*ngIf(pageable)
      (pagerIndexChange)="pageChange($event)"
      [data]="data"
"): ScrollViewComponent@33:32
Parser Error: Unexpected token :, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 1 in [] in ScrollViewComponent@33:32 ("
    </a>
    <kendo-scrollview-pager *ngIf(pageable)
      [ERROR ->](pagerIndexChange)="pageChange($event)"
      [data]="data"
      [activeIndex]="activeIndex""): ScrollViewComponent@34:10
Parser Error: Unexpected token :, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 1 in [] in ScrollViewComponent@33:32 ("<kendo-scrollview-pager *ngIf(pageable)
      (pagerIndexChange)="pageChange($event)"
      [ERROR ->][data]="data"
      [activeIndex]="activeIndex">
    </kendo-scrollview-pager>
"): ScrollViewComponent@35:10
Parser Error: Unexpected token :, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 1 in [] in ScrollViewComponent@33:32 ("
      (pagerIndexChange)="pageChange($event)"
      [data]="data"
      [ERROR ->][activeIndex]="activeIndex">
    </kendo-scrollview-pager>
  </div>
"): ScrollViewComponent@36:10
Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("          <span class="k-icon k-i-arrowhead-e"></span>
    </a>
    <kendo-scrollview-pager [ERROR ->]*ngIf(pageable)
      (pagerIndexChange)="pageChange($event)"
      [data]="data"
"): ScrollViewComponent@33:32
Parser Error: Unexpected token :, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 1 in [] in ScrollViewComponent@33:32 ("
    </a>
    <kendo-scrollview-pager *ngIf(pageable)
      [ERROR ->](pagerIndexChange)="pageChange($event)"
      [data]="data"
      [activeIndex]="activeIndex""): ScrollViewComponent@34:10
Parser Error: Unexpected token :, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 1 in [] in ScrollViewComponent@33:32 ("<kendo-scrollview-pager *ngIf(pageable)
      (pagerIndexChange)="pageChange($event)"
      [ERROR ->][data]="data"
      [activeIndex]="activeIndex">
    </kendo-scrollview-pager>
"): ScrollViewComponent@35:10
Parser Error: Unexpected token :, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 1 in [] in ScrollViewComponent@33:32 ("
      (pagerIndexChange)="pageChange($event)"
      [data]="data"
      [ERROR ->][activeIndex]="activeIndex">
    </kendo-scrollview-pager>
  </div>
"): ScrollViewComponent@36:10
at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:119575:27) [<root>]
at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:7163:16) [<root>]
at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26588:19) [<root>]
at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66630:68) [<root>]
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66513:62 [<root>]
at Set.forEach (native) [<root>]
at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66513:19) [<root>]
at createResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66396:19) [<root>]
at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:175827:43) [<root> => <root>]
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:176234:57 [<root>]
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:175865:47) [<root> => <root>]
at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:176132:35) [<root>]
at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:119575:27) [<root>]
at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:7163:16) [<root>]
at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26588:19) [<root>]
at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66630:68) [<root>]
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66513:62 [<root>]
at Set.forEach (native) [<root>]
at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66513:19) [<root>]
at createResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66396:19) [<root>]
at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:175827:43) [<root> => <root>]
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:176234:57 [<root>]
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:175865:47) [<root> => <root>]
at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:176132:35) [<root>]
at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:176200:31) [<root>]
at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:176185:17) [<root>]
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:176234:17 [<root>]
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:175865:47) [<root> => <root>]
at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:176132:35) [<root>]
```

Any one knows why this is happening.
itried updating all angular related packages to latest as well but error is still their.

please help

Comment: can you provide a plunkr?

Comment: not possible now, as i am not using Kendo UI for scroll view now as Kendo UI for angular still in beta

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to (temporarily) fix it. Navigate to the kendo-angular-scrollview folder: \node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-scrollview\dist\es\scrollview.component.js.

Go to line 312 and replace it with this code here:

`template: "\n      <ul class='k-scrollview'\n        [ngStyle]=\"transitionStyle\"\n        [@animateTo]=\"animationState\"\n        (@animateTo.done)= \"transitionEndHandler($event)\"\n        (kendo.drag) = \"handleDrag($event)\"\n        (kendo.press) = \"handlePress($event)\"\n        (kendo.release) = \"handleRelease($event)\"\n        kendoDraggable>\n        <li *ngFor=\"let item of view;let i=index\"\n          [ngStyle]=\"inlineStyles(i)\"\n          [attr.aria-hidden]=\"i !== 1\">\n            <template\n              [ngTemplateOutlet]=\"itemTemplateRef\"\n              [ngOutletContext]=\"{ item: item }\">\n            </template>\n        </li>\n      </ul>\n      <div class='k-scrollview-elements'\n        [ngStyle]=\"{'height': height}\"\n        *ngIf=\"!isDataSourceEmpty && (pageable||arrows)\">\n        <a class=\"k-scrollview-prev\"\n          aria-label=\"previous\"\n          *ngIf=\"arrows && displayPrevArrow()\"\n          (click)=\"prev()\">\n          <span class=\"k-icon k-i-arrowhead-w\"></span>\n        </a>\n        <a class=\"k-scrollview-next\"\n          aria-label=\"next\"\n          *ngIf=\"arrows && displayNextArrow()\"\n          (click)=\"next()\">\n            <span class=\"k-icon k-i-arrowhead-e\"></span>\n        </a>\n      </div>\n    "`

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as well.  It's a known issue and Telerik will fix it eventually.

To follow the issue:  https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/203

It has something to do with not being able to support the new Angular2 version (released a few days ago).

**The latest update released today (24th Jan 2017) has fixed the issue.  Update your packages and it will have fixed itself.**